# Default Android Studio project gives Unable to resolve dependecies errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've just created a Java project with Android API 19 in Android Studio 3.5.2.

This is the app's build.gradle for reference:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

From the get-go, after the IDE opens the freshly created project I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'activity.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

As recommended in other stackoverflow answers to similar questions, I tried `Build -> Clean Project` and `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`. Also I tried interleaving deleting everything gradle-related from home directory and project files into those steps. Nothing helped.

I do have offline work unchecked. I tried checking it on and off again. It did not help.

What is actually happening and how do I solve this?

Comment: Well, you're using a very old version of Android Studio (the 3.5 it's from 2019) and you have a new Android SDK targeted (SDK 34 is from 2023). Since the [SDK versions must be supported by Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk#get-studio), you can start changing this. My recommendation is that you install the latest version of Android Studio and create the project again.

Comment: What is located in the libs folder that is included in dependencies? Adding dependencies this way is a bit old-style, normally you don't use libraries from file-system.